# Regular expression - String cannot start, end with white-space and consist of few white-spaces in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for  regular expression that allow strings that does not start and does not end with white-space and does not consist of few white-spaces in a row.

Allow:

```
asd asd asd,
asdasd,
asd asd,
```

Disallow:

```
asd   asdasd,
 asdasd,
asdasd  ,
```

Comment: And does that work? whats the question? can you post some example text you'd like to match

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution without look-ahead:

```
^\S+(?: \S+)*$
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cE9uT2/3)

This solution will also match length 1 string like `a`.

I assume that you don't want to allow tabs or new line as the space character. Note that most solutions here don't take into account Unicode spaces, which you would have to manually specify to prevent their matches.

Comment: This solution is the best because as you noticed other does not allow single letter string :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\S(?!.*\s{2}).*?\S$/
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` line start
- `\S` - match a non space at start
- `(?!.*\s{2})` negative lookahead to disallow 2 consecutive spaces
- `.*?` - match any character (0 or more, non-greedy)
- `\S` - match a non space at end
- `$` - line end

Comment: what about multiple white-spaces inside?

Comment: Does not allow to add single letter

Comment: How about matching an empty string as valid input since that also meets your conditions.

Comment: only single white space also is valid

Comment: Yes I like his regex too but you didn't have the clear requirement of allowing single letter in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
/((^[^\s]).*?([^\s]$))/
```

Edit: (Explanation,)

`^` match line start,

`[^\s]` match anything that is not a space

`.*?` match any character

`$` match line end

EDIT:

if you want to remove the possibility of adjacent spaces from string you can use this regex.

```
/((^(?!\s))(\w|\s(?!\s+))+((?<!\s)$))/
```

above regex may not work in javascript because of the negative lookbehind at the end but works fine for python.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: This solution allows multiple spaces inside string

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*[ ](?=[ ]))\S.*?\S$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/33

Comment: Does not allow to add single letter